# Perl command line problem

Tags: perl, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I'm writing a Perl program that will take a few command-line arguments (they'll actually be supplied by another program) and open a pdf to a specific page. I based it off of [here](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) (Look at page 5). I've already tested the command straight from the command line, and it does exactly what I want it to do. Now I'm trying to do it from Perl, and it doesn't appear to be working. The error I get is:

```
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe
```

Here's the code... can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!C:/perl/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $c = `cmd \c "`.$ARGV[0].`" /A "page=`.$ARGV[1].`=OpenActions" "`.$ARGV[2].``;
print $c;
system "Pause";
```

All I get after this is a blank space in cmd. Once I hit Ctrl+C, it returns to a prompt, and if I hit enter there, it gives me the above error.

Comment: Are you using the backtick (`) instead of a single quote (') in assembling your command string?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the backtick. The backtick is the one above the tab key, right?

Comment: BTW, what is cmd \c supposed to be? Should it not read cmd /c

Comment: Yeah, Ingo, thanks. That actually cleared the program right up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Perl sees

```
my $c = `cmd \c "`.$ARGV[0].`" /A "page=`.$ARGV[1].`=OpenActions" "`.$ARGV[2].``;
```

It turns it into something like this:

```
my $c = qx{cmd \c "}.$ARGV[0].qx{" /A "page=}.
        $ARGV[1].qx{=OpenActions" "}.$ARGV[2].qx{};
```

Each of those `qx{...}` portions, are executed by the command shell as they are encountered, most of them are probably syntax errors. Your full command is never run.

What you probably wanted was:

```
my $c = qx{cmd \\c "$ARGV[0]" /A "page=$ARGV[1]=OpenActions" "$ARGV[2]"};
```

Which constructs the string, and then passes it to the shell.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up the backtick thing. But, and I hate to say this, the situation hasn't changed. It still does the same thing as before...

Comment: In the end, even with Ingo's answer, my original program's command didn't work, so I resorted to this. Which is why the answer is this.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're a little confused about how backticks work. Something like this:

```
my $c = `/where_is/pancake_house`
```

Will run the `/where_is/pancake_house` command and put whatever it prints on its standard output into `$c`. Backticks also interpolate like double quote strings. You'll also have to escape backslashes.

So, you don't want multiple sets of backticks in command and you don't need to paste things together like that. Something like this:

```
my $c = `cmd \\c "$ARGV[0]" /A "page=$ARGV[1]=OpenActions" "$ARGV[2]`;
```

should be okay. Of course you'll still have issues if the `ARGV` values have spaces or quotes or other funny things. You'd probably want to use [`IPC::Open2`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.12.3/ext/IPC-Open2/lib/IPC/Open2.pm) or [`IPC::Open3`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.12.3/ext/IPC-Open3/lib/IPC/Open3.pm) for more safety.

Comment: I tried adding what you said, but it still returns the same error. Thanks for trying, though. (Yes, it was copied and pasted)

Answer (score 3):

Backtick doesn't work like you seem to think.

```
$var = "foo";
`cmd \c `.$foo
```

This does not execute the command `cmd \c foo`. It executes the command `cmd \c` and takes the output, concatenates the value of `$foo` to that output. You need to construct the entire command, and only then feed it to the backtick operator.

Comment: This also teaches me more about Perl... thanks. I didn't know that(obviously).